# How to fetch text from a page using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I recently needed to make a PHP file fetch the text from a page, and display it but I did not know how to do it.

My current code is:

https://pastebin.com/Zhh4SS3L

```
        $results["registeredname"] = "here shall be the domain";
    $results["productname"] = "this shall be fetched";
    $results["productid"] = "5";
    $results["billingcycle"] = "Monthly";
    $results["validdomains"] = $this->getHostDomain();
    $results["validips"] = $this->getHostIP();
    $results["validdirs"] = $this->getHostDir();
    $results["checkdate"] = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
    $results["version"] = "this shall be fetched";
    $results["regdate"] = "this shall be fetched";
    $results["nextduedate"] ="this shall be fetched";;
    $results["addons"] = array(array('name' => 'Branding Removal', 'nextduedate' => "this shall be fetched";', 'status'
```

Any advices are good!

Comment: "this shall be fetched" - from where?

Comment: I would e hosting the text to be fetched as well.

Comment: That does not answer the question. From _where_ - a text file, a database, an HTTP endpoint, …? You need to be clear on what you actually want at least first, before we can possibly help you. And once you decided this, you should also do a bit more research first - “did not know how to do it” is a bit too little effort, for asking a question on this site. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this reminds me of something I was playing with last year. As I do not have the exact values you're planning to fetch.. I'll show you an example of what I was playing with using cURL. It should help.

I changed my website a bit, so it probably doesn't return anything anymore (but who knows haha), but I know for a fact that it **worked for me**, so the point is still there.

The basic gist of it was - enter a page, post searched term, return whatever was on the page. In addition to what you want, this will POST a value to the URL, but you can skip the POST part. If the data is behind a login or something.

```
/*
 * TESTING GROUNDS
 *
 * A. Goal: Search (toms.click/search) and return found articles page
 * website = toms.click
 *
 * word to search for (1 match): axiom
 *
 * condition for submit:
 * if (isset($_POST['searchSubmit']) && isset($_POST['searchbar'])) { ... }
 * → ['searchSubmit' => 'GO', 'searchbar' => 'axiom']
 *
 *
 * form layout:
 * <form method="POST" action="https://toms.click/search">
        <input class="search-bar" type="search" name="searchbar" placeholder="Search" minlength="3" title="search the website" required=""><!--
        whitespace removal between searchbar and submit
        --><input class="submit" name="searchSubmit" type="submit" value="Go">
   </form>
 *


/**
 * @param $searchbar string whatever you'd type into the searchbar
 * @return string
 */
function remoteSearch($searchbar)
{
    $url = 'https://toms.click/search'; //The URL of what you want to fetch / enter / post to

    /** @var array $fields what we're going to post, $fields['a'] = 'b' is $_POST['a'] = 'b' */
    $fields = array(
        'searchSubmit' => 'GO',
        'searchbar' => $searchbar
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    //Set our target url (login script)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    //Enable post and load a post query
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));

    //HTTPs, don't verify it for now
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    //Enable up to 10 redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

    //We want whatever is on the other side
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

You can use this to easily grab stuff, so I guess you could use it.

Hope this helps or points you in the right direction :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hi @andari-axysto, glad it helped, if this solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. 
And welcome to Stack Overflow :)